# How do I set an image's resolution?

Tags: swing, clojure, seesaw

I am using Seesaw to interact with Swing.

I have some icons defined thus:

```
(def label :icon 
           (clojure.java.io/resource "some_image.png"))
```

I want to render "some_image.png" in a different resolution. If I simply set the bounds, I'll only get part of the image.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: i'm assuming you meant something like `(def mylabel (label :icon (clojure.java.io/resource "some_image.png")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it by dropping down into Swing. basically, manipulate the file as a Swing Image. once you have it at the size you want, Seesaw's `icon` facilities are flexible in terms of what can be passed in (see https://daveray.github.io/seesaw/seesaw.icon-api.html); you can pass the Swing Image into the `label` function.

```
(defn imagetest []
  (let [w (frame :title "Image Test" :width 400 :height 400)
        img (.getScaledInstance 
              (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read 
                (io/resource "racecar.gif")) 400 400 1)
        lbl (label :icon img)
        pnl (horizontal-panel :items [lbl])]
    (config! w :content pnl)
    (show! w)))
```

Note: the `1` that i'm passing as the final arg to `.getScaledInstance` is for the `SCALE_DEFAULT` flag; more info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.Image.SCALE_DEFAULT